# Windows Phone 8 - Best Template

Tags: templates, windows-phone

I am planning a Windows Phone 8 Mobile application and wondering which template is the best for the project.

In simple terms, the project will be pulling information from a Web Service and shall display data in a Grid-Like fashion. The information will simply be boxes with text inside.

There will be other pages such as Information (static) and Tweets which is self explanatory.

I would like to use the Panorama Template as it's quite pretty and fluid. The application does not require any such user validation, i.e. there will be no text-boxes for the user to input any data. It simply displays data.

The most important key is functionality but native look and feel is equally as important.

I just want to get a feel of what other people think and which app template is best suited for the type of project.

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what design you want really. I like apps that have a panorama as the first screen and it quite common. I would also avoid using a Pivot unless you are actually doing something like the email app where you swipe between different filters on a list, as that's its intended purpose.

All the templates are essentially just picking a pre made layout. If you change your mind later you won't have any issue changing it. There's no fundamental difference in the app.